Why is it punishable to refuse to sign a traffic ticket in some states in the United States?
In the United States, the 5th amendment instates the absolute right to not be forced to testify against oneself.
With this being said, states such as California and Pennsylvania, it can be a crime to not sign a traffic ticket, and in more states yet, refusal to sign will land you in jail.
This on its face would seem to violate the 5th amendment, as your refusal to testify (sign the certification) will result in the state bringing punishment against you.
The argument I see online usually goes something along the lines of "Signing the ticket isn't an admission of guilt, but actually admits that ...". This doesn't alleviate the claim in the following ways:

It does not matter if you are charged with a crime in this case, nor does it matter if you're testifying to (or not to) committing any crime. This is because the direct effect of not signing is the enactment of the penalty of imprisonment.
Even if the ticket doesn't testify that you broke the law, this is still admissible evidence in court, which could be used against you.

So with this in mind, it appears on its face that you must either:

Provide the state with evidence against yourself in a criminal case,

OR

Endure the punishment of jail time.

Further, some arguments online say that signing these tickets grants you a privilege to be released, and it is not a part of your 5th amendment right. I don't find this convincing either, as above, the option to not testify is what induces a punishment specifically. Combine this with the common idea that exercising a right will give you no greater punishment than not exercising a right, and we can see that the idea that signing the ticket grants a 'privilege' is simply an inversion of the idea, with no greater argumentative force.
with these two things in mind, how has the law found that it's OK for the state enforce this system despite the 5th amendment rights afforded to citizens?

"states such as California and Pennsylvania, it can be a crime to not sign a traffic ticket" Source?

A traffic offense is not a criminal offense in most states, so the 5th Amendment doesn't apply to it. You can legally be forced to testify against yourself on pain of incarceration in a traffic offense case if it is a civil traffic offense (like speeding) and not a misdemeanor (like DUI). Your assertion that this doesn't matter is legally incorrect. Whether you find this convincing or not doesn't matter since you don't get to decide what is and is not the law.

@ohwilleke if we're going to playpretend that you lose your 5th amendment rights because  someone came up with a new name for "criminal offense" with the same effects, I'd rather close this question. If it quacks like a duck, and it walks like a duck, and looks like a duck, it's a duck, and this is quackery.

@tuskiomi The law on the matter is perfectly clear, and the difference is material. see, e.g., https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-i-get-out-of-a-traffic-ticket-by-pleading-the--2065767.html You can't go to jail as a punishment for being convicted of a traffic offense, but  you can go to jail for a crime. The fact that you stubbornly want to ignore what the law actually says is irrelevant.

@ohwilleke are you sure about that? In California speeding can be considered "reckless driving", which is in fact a crime (misdemeanor). Also, this

@ohwilleke one can't go to jail for committing a traffic offense... unless they refuse to sign legal evidence, then they get put in jail (but it's still not a crime! so no 5th amendment rights! D'oh!). I'm sorry, but your statement takes more mental gymnastics to process then I'm presently capable of producing.

@tuskiomi Your belief that this is legal evidence related to the traffic offense is still wrong. The crime, if there is one, is akin to resisting arrest. You can be jailed for slugging a cop trying to arrest you even if you are completely innocent of and never charged with the underlying crime that is the basis of the arrest.

@littleadv The analytical distinction I'm making is between traffic offenses charged in a ticket which are not punishable by jail and those that are. Reckless driving involving traveling at a high speed is a different offense than driving five miles over the limit and facing a fine.

@tuskiomi you're missing the point. Refusing to show up in court is the problem, and in fact may in some cases be a crime. For whatever reason, not just traffic stops. If you get a subpoena and you don't show up - you can be dragged to court in a similar fashion.

You are not testifying against yourself when you sign a ticket.
You are agreeing to take care of it or appear in court to do so.  If you refuse to sign indicating you will take care of it, the officer will take you in to ensure you do.  The signature process is a way to make it easier on everyone, cops don't want to arrest people for speeding.  But if you insist on making it hard, the cops will go right along.
A traffic ticket is the cop telling you that you are being charged with breaking the law.  How easy or hard it is for you is then up to the driver.

"You are not testifying against yourself when you sign a ticket." Unless the signature is inadmissible as evidence in court, I do not believe this.

"Unless the signature is inadmissible as evidence in court" Evidence of what, exactly?

@tuskiomi The signature is not evidence that you committed the traffic offense, it is evidence that the officer delivered to the piece of paper charging you with a traffic offense to you.

@tuskiomi believe what you want, you will take a trip to the station if you refuse to sign.

@TigerGuy that doesn't help your answer.

@user102008 absolutely any evidence which the 5th amendment would normally protect you from giving against yourself. it matters not what the evidence is, only that it's normally protected.

@tuskiomi: "Any" could mean something or nothing at all, so your statement is completely meaningless. You haven't given one single example of what it could be evidence of. Your signing is not evidence of anything other than that you saw the paper. You are not testifying or making any statements of fact on the paper.

@tuskiomi Downvote the answer if you like, but you seem to not want the site's advice.

There's no punishment in California for refusing to sign a traffic ticket.
Signing a traffic ticket is not an admittance of guilt, it's an admittance of receiving the ticket (= summons to court). If you refuse to sign it, the law enforcement will then be forced to bring you to court to ensure your appearance.
See the CVC Sec. 40302:

Whenever any person is arrested for any violation of this code, not declared to be a felony, the arrested person shall be taken without unnecessary delay before a magistrate within the county in which the offense charged is alleged to have been committed and who has jurisdiction of the offense and is nearest or most accessible with reference to the place where the arrest is made in any of the following cases:
(a) When the person arrested fails to present both his or her driver’s license or other satisfactory evidence of his or her identity and an unobstructed view of his or her full face for examination.
(b) When the person arrested refuses to give his or her written promise to appear in court.
(c) When the person arrested demands an immediate appearance before a magistrate.
(d) When the person arrested is charged with violating Section 23152.

The signature on the ticket is the written promise to appear in court, refusing to provide it will force the police to bring the violator to the traffic court immediately under CVC 40302(b). That's not punishment, the point is to ensure that you show up in court.

I apologize, I addressed this precise argument in my question, but after I posted it.  In short, a right grants you immunity from governmental punishment for doing (or not doing) certain actions. I don't find it convincing that being forced to to jail, and wait to go before a court is in fact not a punishment

@tuskiomi bringing you to court is not punishment, it's part of what law enforcement does. You can make your life easier if you promise to come to court on your own volition, but you have to show up in court one way or another and if you refuse to promise to do so on your own - you'll be forced to do so. That's not a punishment.

does this change the argument any then? investigators can't buy you admission to the amusement park if you sign an affidavit, why can they let you bypass the normal procedures in this specific case?

@tuskiomi I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that handcuffing people and hauling them directly to court from any traffic stop is somehow better than having them promise to come on their own at a later scheduled time?

What if you do sign the ticket but then still don't show up for court when invited to do so?

@PMF If it's a civil violation, judgment can be entered against you by default.
